# Append HTML Elements to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

at the moment iam developing a little content editor for wordpress (javascript only). Temporary i save everything in an javascript object. At first i wanted to stringify the object with JSON and then do the rest with php.

BUT .... since it's a live editor and i got the "final" HTML code already in the editor i thought why all the effort and not just save the HTML Code created with the editor.

Problem now is the how... after writing the whole editor iam to dumb to do this.

This is how i do it atm, it works but i don't if thats a good and save solution to do this:

After you hit 'save' it just append the html structure of my 'content' to a textarea with the attribute contenteditable="true".

```
$('#contentHolder').append($('#content'));
```

What do you guys think? Thanks a lot for any feedback. :)

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: What is the problem? You don't know how to save your HTML or you don't know if it is a good idea to use a textarea for that?

Comment: Yes thats the questions, whats the best way to save my generated html to the database. Sorry for the misleading title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `textarea` elements accept plain text only. What you need is another element, such as a `<div>`, with the `contenteditable="true"` set. Then you'll be able to append HTML code to it. Setting the `contenteditable` attribute on a `textarea` won't do anything, since it already is editable in the first place.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y66sX/)

Comment: But how to get it save to the DB? I need to append my content to some element that gets parsed on POST and saved.

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript to parse the contents of the `div`, and filter out any tags, so you'll just keep the text only.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joey but i want to do the exact opposite. I want to save the whole html structure of my content, like you got it if you save with a wysiwyg editor. Maybe iam to tired at the moment but i cant figured it out.

Comment: Then you simply take the HTML contents of the div, and submit that to the database, also via JavaScript. You can't submit a WYSIWYG editor's contents any other way. Either you convert the WYSIWYG editor's contents to a `textarea`'s contents via JavaScript, and submit the form to the database, or you submit the contents to the database via XHR in JavaScript

Comment: Ill try both, thanks a lot Joey :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that useless topic, that was the answer in the end:

```
var content = $('#content').html();
$('#textarea').val(content);
```